# Using Google Maps Coordinate System in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-maps-api

I have some Points in Shapefile with BC Albers Coordinate Syetem and I need to Project them to Google Maps Lat and Long. I tried to do this by using

```
WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator EPSG: 3857
```

and

```
WGS84 EPSG: 4326
```

But none of them returning correct result! I believe there is Coordinate for Google Maps in ArcGIS as "Web Mercator" to do this but I couldn't find it in QGis.

What Coordinate should I use for Getting correct points X and Y on google map?

I also used `EPSG:900913 Google Mercator` but when I tried to get X and Y coords through Geometry Tool/ Export add Geometry Columns I am getting numbers like :

[image]

Result using EPSG:3857:

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for lat/longs, then 4326 is your destination coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks Mintx 4326 looks more like lat and long but what I am getting are wrong coordinates!

Comment: Could you give an example of a coordinate before and after converting?

Comment: Like actual file?

Comment: It looks like some of your source coordinates are swapped. If the area of interest isn't too large and should relatively near Vancouver, all x values should be >1 million. Thus point 1, 9, 13, etc need their values swapped.

Comment: but they all looks good im BC I mean even in QGIS they are all in BC layer

Comment: The first row in your CSV has X/Y of `707619.48,1312779.213` - what incorrect lat/long value are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is first display your CSV in the proper coordinate system (BC Albers) so QGIS can then re-project it to Google Maps Mercator (3857).

**[EPSG:3857 -- WGS84 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/)** is what you want.

So what you need to do is add your CSV to QGIS using 'Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer'.

Choose the default options in the first window:

[image]

The next window will ask you what coordinate system you want to use to display your X and Y values. You know it is in BC Albers, so choose that option in the dialogue box:

[image]

Now your points - still in BC Albers - will display in QGIS - but this is tricky because you will have a hard time displaying the various OpenLayers backgrounds with this data.

Here are the points on their own:

[image]

The last step is to actually re-project your data to Google Maps projection

Right-click the sample (CSV / delimited) layer in QGIS > Save As

**Format**: ESRI Shapefile
**Save as**: give your new SHP a name
**CRS**: Selected CRS > choose EPSG:3857 WGS84 / Psuedo Mercator**

Click **OK** to export and re-project your CSV to SHP in 3857

Now create a new map (to reset the coordinate system of the QGIS project)

Add your SHP you saved, and from the Web > OpenLayers menu add one of the basemaps:

[image]

That should do it!

Updates:

**The difference between EPSG:3857 and EPSG:3785 in QGIS is confusing, and I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of 3785 is... Most if not all web map systems are published using EPSG:3857 yet in QGIS the description for 3785 is "Popular Visualization CRS / Mercator" and the description for the CORRECT web mercator is "WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator". I will take up this issue somewhere else!

Update #2: I see in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62838/transform-from-wgs84-to-epsg-3785-google-maps) that 3785 is the deprecated version of the 'google maps' coordinate system... I hope QGIS can make note of this soon...

Comment: Thanks MapBaker but I am not getting Correct value for X and Y at EPSG:3857!

Comment: I uploaded an image showing the result of X and Y at EPSG:3857, can you please take a look at that?

Comment: @Behseini updated my answer with the correct CRS/EPSG value and the steps to get your data working correctly...

Comment: @Behseini you are welcome!!! good luck!