# How to load my CSV file with WKT to QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, csv, qgis-openlayers-plugin

This is my first project regarding QGIS. My problem is I have a CSV file:

```
shapeId, gpsPoint=lat, gpsPoint=lon, length, segments, lengthJson, segmentsJson, name, gpsAltitude, isBoundary, wkt 
1, 8.510618353052012, 76.95793988850774, null, null, "[20.0,26.0,95.0,11.0,77.0,11.0,63.0,23.0,9.0,40.0,20.0]", "[{""x"":650,""y"":166},{""x"":592,""y"":137},{""x"":510,""y"":119},{""x"":328,""y"":363},{""x"":324,""y"":398},{""x"":449,""y"":609},{""x"":484,""y"":608},{""x"":634,""y"":473},{""x"":651,""y"":401},{""x"":639,""y"":374},{""x"":647,""y"":246},{""x"":650,""y"":166}]", palace boundary, -173.23912770954138, true, "POLYGON ((8.510618353052012 76.95793988850774, 8.510262287 76.957779182, 8.510040369 76.957551036, 8.51076993 76.957428227, 8.510874635 76.957425526, 8.511509332 76.95751038, 8.511496826 76.957609161, 8.511093044 76.957710407, 8.510878582 76.957721834, 8.510799786 76.957713931, 8.510417299 76.957719325, 8.510618353052012 76.95793988850774))"
```

When I load all these points in [maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps) my coordinates are at correct positions. But when I load the CSV file to QGIS and open in Google Maps via *OpenLayers Plugin* it's totally wrong I don't know how to proceed.

I have gone through [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132510/qgis-google-maps-coordinate-system) link but still my coordinates appear somewhere else.

**Update** Please see this image

[image]

At the end of the csv file there is a field called *wkt* which I need to show on maps.

Comment: *OpenLayer Plugin* does not manage well projection. Use *QuickMapServices* extension instead or you will not find out if the issue is with the plugin or your csv data import

Comment: @ThomasG77 Okay I will try now a let u know

Comment: @ThomasG77 I tried with _QuickMapsServices_ but its the same issue

Comment: I obtain this result https://img42.com/hxRWM It the expected or the wrong one? Did you activate On the fly reprojection in your QGIS project properties?

Comment: @ThomasG77 Yes this is the expected result...how did u get it ?

Comment: @ThomasG77 yes On the fly CRS transformatin is enabled I just checked

Comment: Your file has lat,long, a bunch of xy's as well as a Polygon. Which one do you want to show?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I want to show the wkt field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use QuickMapServices plugin instead of OpenLayers Plugin.

**If you want to use coordinates to display point**

To make things work, I just used the Layer > AddLayer > Add Delimited TextLayer

It seems the trailing character *`* in line 2 of your sample make the layer opening fails. I also renamed "gpsPoint=lat" to "lat"  and "gpsPoint=lon" to "lon" (not mandatory, you should avoid field names like this)

See the screenshots for detailed use case

[image: Parameters to open specific CSV file]

I didn't tick the CSV file format because your CSV is quoted.

[image: Projection to choose]

EPSG 4326 = projection of GPS = decimal degrees = latitude, longitude

**If you want to use the wkt polygon**

As stated by other in comment, it works but it seems you want wkt polygon.

It seems that lat, lon order is reverted.

- You will have to open the csv file like with previous solution but choose Geometry definition to WKT. You will see the position is wrong.
- You have to save the layer as Shapefile with Save As and add it to the canevas
- Use QGIS native Processing Toolbox algorithm "Swap X and Y coordinates" <s>Install the plugin SWAP XY and apply the swap process to the previous shapefile layer</s>

PS: it seems that lat,lon or lon,lat order both exists in practice with WKT.

Comment: am sorry to say but still this is what I get. I followed just as u said. I have updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: Can you share the screenshot using pics sharing like https://imgur.com ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort Its working now...!!! I was using lat , lon not lon , lat. I got it from your solution.

Comment: @elsa This does not seem to solve your problem, or the question is not clear. You are not showing your WKT Field (that is a polygon) on the map, but rather a single point.

Comment: I've completed my answer with both solutions: lat,lon point based, wkt polygon based